# Jquery: Pulling flickr set + getting item.title

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

I'm trying to pull a set of images from flickr:

```
<ul class="thumb">  
 <li>  
  <p class="artisan-name">item.title</p>  
  <img src="item.photo">  
 </li>  
  ..... as many li's as there are photos in the set  
</ul>
```

So far, I have the photos wrapped in the li, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get the p to come before the img within the ul.

what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157623815188370&    
nsid=12295778@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){  
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){  
$("#title").html(item.title);   
$("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("ul.thumb")  
.wrap("<li>");  
});  
});  
});  
</script>   
<ul class="thumb"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var listItems = '';

$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
   // construct the html string
   // do NOT manipulate DOM inside a loop
   // it's to costly
   listItems
       += '<li>'+
            '<p class="artisan-name">'+item.title+'</p>'+
            '<img src="'+item.media.m+'" />'+
          '</li>';
});

// manipulate the DOM only once 
// to add all the li elements
$('ul.thumb').append(listItems);
```

---

**Update**: Here is the complete code (comments removed)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157623815188370&nsid=12295778@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){  
        var listItems = '';
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
           listItems
               += '<li>'+
                    '<p class="artisan-name">'+item.title+'</p>'+
                    '<img src="'+item.media.m+'" />'+
                  '</li>';
        });
        $('ul.thumb').append(listItems);
    });  
});
```

Comment: I tried adding it to my markup [added var.... immediately after ...function(data){.. ] but it didn't work. I think the reasoning you give is the more correct answer but couldn't implement it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @isa blanche: You should add `var listItems = '';` right at the point where I am adding it for it to work. Follow my code, and it will definitely work. However, it's up to you to decide what works best for you. I am just letting you know that modifying the DOM inside the loop is going to be slow as hell compared to the solution I am suggesting above.

Comment: Sorry for my lacking knowledge of jquery, I added it where you had it, after the $.getJSON function. I thought that's where you had it?

Comment: I updated my answer with the complete code. That should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
   $("#title").html(item.title);
   var liElem=$('<li/>').append('<p>'+item.title+'</p>');
   $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(liElem);
   liElem.appendTo("ul.thumb");
});
```

For better performances:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function() {  
         $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157623815188370&    
nsid=12295778@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
            if(data.items && data.items.length){
                var arrLength=data.items.length,v='',dataHtml='';
                for(var i=0;i<arrLength;++i){
                    v=data.items[i];
                    if(v.media && v.media.m) dataHtml+='<li><p>'+(v.title||'')+'</p><img src="'+v.media.m+'" alt=""/></li>';
                }
                $('ul.thumb').append(dataHtml);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! For some reason that isn't working for me. See: http://shop.indegoafrica.org/pages/meet-the-artisans#fragment-2